# Test App in Xcode Crashes on click of a button, but not a switch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm making a test application in Xcode to learn objective-c, but when I click on the button in my app, it crashes.

My Viewcontroller.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
        IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
        UIButton *myButton;
        UISwitch *mySwitch;
        BOOL switched;


    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
    @property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

    -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)switchMoved:(id)sender;


    @end
```

My Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myButton;
@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize mySwitch;

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    sleep(1);
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

-(IBAction)switchMoved:(id)sender{
    if(switched == TRUE){
        [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        switched = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        switched = TRUE;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [myLabel setText:@"This is a label"];
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    switched = TRUE;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The app crashes when I click the button in the simulator, but not when I switch the switch back and forth. Why is this happening? All of the outlets are connected correctly.

Comment: What's the message in the crashlog?

Comment: BTW you will not see myLabel change first to blue and then red, it will just go red. The GUI doesn't update as each individual line is executing, it will update next time the run loop gets to execute (something new for you to learn).

Comment: my first thought is go back to the xib/storyboard right-click on the button and check there's mistakenly connected outlets/actions. The code looks fine, and usually it;s because there's a faulty connection in the drawn UI.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `sleep(1)`, which blocks the main thread and thus any UI-interaction/updates (as @Martin H also said in the comments), try to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` which will run the method given after a delay.

Here's an example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeTextColor:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

}

- (void)changeTextColor:(id)sender {
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

// Edit: Oh… I'm posting this because I (as others) can't seem to find anything wrong with the code. Perhaps a wrong IB-binding. Perhaps you need to reset the the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I use GCD instead of perform selector but either should work. He's my implementation using GCD. You should never use sleep(); for UI changes. Either animation, perform selector, or GCD.

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [self setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    dispatch_time_t waitTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,(int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_after(waitTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{  
  [self setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] 
});
}
```